# Необходимо получить список друзей пользователя вконтакте по uid

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Я пробовал использовать метод friends.get. Но мне возвращается список моих друзей, вне зависимости от uid. В теории должны возвращаться друзья указанного пользователя.

Общая задача: Есть список пользователей. Необходимо получить кол-во друзей и подписчиков, а так же кол-во "собачек".

Я не понимаю, что я делаю не так

```
import requests
from VK_parsing_data import offset

i = 0
for user in users:
    print(user)
    member_request_params = (
        ('user_ids', user),
        ('order', 'name'),
        ('count', 1000),
        ('offset', offset),
        ('fields', 'last_seen'),
        ('version', 5.74))
    r = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get', params=member_request_params).json()
    print(user, r)
```

Comment: У метода friends.get не существует опции user_ids, [читайте документацию](https://vk.com/dev/friends.get)

Answer (score 0):

Неверно написал запрос. Необходимо передавать в запрос `user_id`,  а не `user_ids`.